# How to create a new file with required columns from different multiple files in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, cut, join, gawk

I have a directory `ballgown`, in which there are around 1000 subdirectories as sample names. Each subdirectory has a file `t_data.ctab`. The filename is the same in all subdirectories.

```
ballgown
      |_______TCGA-A2-A0T3-01A
                   |___________ t_data.ctab
      |_______TCGA-A7-A4SA-01A
                   |___________ t_data.ctab
      |_______TCGA-A7-A6VW-01A
                   |___________ t_data.ctab
```

Like above `ballgown` has 1000 subdirectories. The `t_data.ctab` file in all those 1000 subdirectories looks like below with columns:

```
t_id    chr     strand  start   end     t_name  num_exons       length  gene_id gene_name       cov     FPKM
1       1       -       10060   10614   MSTRG.1.1       1       555     MSTRG.1 .       0.000000        0.000000
2       1       +       11140   30023   MSTRG.10.1      12      3981    MSTRG.10        .       2.052715        0.284182
3       1       -       11694   29342   MSTRG.11.1      8       6356    MSTRG.11        .       0.557588        0.077194
4       1       +       11869   14409   ENST00000456328.2       3       1657    MSTRG.10        DDX11L1 0.000000        0.000000
5       1       +       11937   29347   MSTRG.10.3      12      3544    MSTRG.10        .       0.000000        0.000000
6       1       -       11959   30203   MSTRG.11.2      11      4547    MSTRG.11        .       0.369929        0.051214
7       1       +       12010   13670   ENST00000450305.2       6       632     MSTRG.10        DDX11L1 0.000000        0.000000
8       1       +       12108   26994   MSTRG.10.5      10      5569    MSTRG.10        .       0.057091        0.007904
9       1       +       12804   199997  MSTRG.10.6      12      3567    MSTRG.10        .       0.000000        0.000000
10      1       +       13010   31097   MSTRG.10.7      12      4375    MSTRG.10        .       0.000000        0.000000
11      1       -       13068   26832   MSTRG.11.3      9       5457    MSTRG.11        .       0.995280        0.137788
```

From all the `t_data.ctab` files I want to extract only `t_name` and `FPKM` column and create a new file. In the new file the `FPKM` column should be the sample name. It should look like below:

```
t_name         TCGA-A2-A0T3-01A TCGA-A7-A4SA-01A    TCGA-A7-A6VW-01A
MSTRG.1.1              0            0.028181                 0
MSTRG.10.1         0.284182         0.002072             0.046302
MSTRG.11.1         0.077194         0.685535             0.105849
ENST00000456328.2      0            0.307315             0.038961
MSTRG.10.3             0            0.446015             0.009946
MSTRG.11.2         0.051214         0.053577             0.036081
ENST00000450305.2      0            0.110438             0.040319
MSTRG.10.5         0.007904             0                1.430825
MSTRG.10.6             0                0                0.221105
MSTRG.10.7             0            0.199354                 0
MSTRG.11.3         0.137788         0.004792                 0
```

If it is two or three files I can use `cut` -f6,12 on each file and then join them. But I have around 1000 files now.

Comment: Is the `t_name` column exactly the same in all files?

Comment: @simlev Yes, it is.

Comment: You could run `cut -f6` on any file to create the first column, then `find` all files and use `awk` or `perl` on them, to add a subsequent column for each.

Comment: I'd recommend you output in CSV format: with 1000 columns, you'll want to use a spreadsheet program to view the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple way:

first do:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { print substr(FILENAME,1,16) >substr(FILENAME,1,16)".tmp" }
     FNR >1 { print $12 > substr(FILENAME,1,16)".tmp" }
     NR==FNR{ print $6  >"first_column.tmp" }' TCGA-A*/t_data.ctab
```

then `paste` them together with comma delimited file (remove `-d,` if you want to have Tab instead):

```
paste -d, *.tmp
t_name,TCGA-A2-A0T3-01A,TCGA-A7-A4SA-01A,TCGA-A7-A6VW-01A
MSTRG.1.1,0.000000,0.00000,0.0000
MSTRG.10.1,0.284182,0.28418,0.2841
MSTRG.11.1,0.077194,0.07719,0.0771
ENST00000456328.2,0.000000,0.00000,0.0000
MSTRG.10.3,0.000000,0.00000,0.0000
MSTRG.11.2,0.051214,0.05121,0.0512
ENST00000450305.2,0.000000,0.00000,0.0000
MSTRG.10.5,0.007904,0.00790,0.0079
MSTRG.10.6,0.000000,0.00000,0.0000
MSTRG.10.7,0.000000,0.00000,0.0000
MSTRG.11.3,0.137788,0.13778,0.1377
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you be satisfied with csv output?

```
find ballgown -name t_data.ctab | awk ' {
  F=$0
  print F " started"
  split(F,P,"/")
  FN= P[2]
  TF[FN]=1
  getline < F
  while ((getline < F) > 0) {
    TN[$6]=1
    TV[FN ":" $6] = $NF
  }
  close(F)
  print f " done"
}
END {
  printf("tname")
  for (F in TF) {
    printf(", %s",F)
  }
  print ""
  for (N in TN) {
    printf("%s",N)
    for (F in TF) {
      printf(", %s",TV[F ":" N])
    }
    print ""
  }
}
'
```

Comment: I wrote this code in a shell script "eg.sh". Then I gave sh eg.sh > eg.csv; Is this right?

Comment: If you made the script executable and put it somewhere on $PATH, then yes.

Comment: In the starting of shell script I gave #!/bin/bash; and then I gave the code you posted. As I said before on the command line I gave sh eg.sh > eg.csv; looks like it is running. but its been one hour but didn't finish yet anything.

Comment: It depends on the size and number of those files.  To see if it advances, I'd add a "print F" after the "F=$0" and "close(F)" statements, and restart the script.

Comment: could you please make this changes in the above code. thank you

Comment: now run  "eg.sh | grep -Ev '(started|done)$' > eg.csv;"   BTW. how much lines does each file contain in reality?

Comment: Each file has 395099 lines

Comment: That is slightly more than you gave in your sample. You may run out of memory. Before I waste any more time with this, what will you do with the result, an array with 400 million cells?

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the problem in two operations, as described in the comment to the question. This is possible since the first column is exactly the same for each file, and every file has the same number of lines.

Position yourself in the ballgown directory:

```
cd ballgown
```

As a first step, create an output file containing the first column:

```
cut -f6 TCGA-A7-A6VW-01A/t_data.ctab > out.tab
```

The bulk of the work is done by a combination of `find` and `perl`:

```
find -iname t_data.ctab -exec perl -i.bak -lane 'if($.==1){$ARGV=~/([-\w]+)\/.*$/;$f=$1} if(1..eof&&($n=$.)){$a[$.]=$F[11];$a[1]=$f;next}; print "$_\t$a[$.-$n]"' {} out.tab \;
```

**Note:** This is a destructive action; original files will be preserved with an added `.bak` extension.

---

Non-destructive version, making use of `sponge` (also, `find` was replaced by a `for` loop):

```
for F in */t_data.ctab; do perl -lane 'if(1..eof&&($n=$.)){$a[$.]=$F[11];$a[1]=$ARGV=~s/([-\w]+)\/.*$/$1/r;next} print "$_\t$a[$.-$n]"' $F out.tab | sponge out.tab; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully programmatic solution, in **PHP**.

```
<?php
$filenames = glob('*/t_data.ctab');
foreach($filenames as $k=>$filename) {
    $name = pathinfo($filename)['dirname'] . "\n";
    $file = file($filename);
    foreach ($file as $n => $line) {
        $line = explode("\t", $line);
        if ($n === 0) {
            $line[11] = $name;
        }
        if ($k === 0) {
            $out[$n] = $line[5] . "\t" . $line[11];
        } else {
            $out[$n] = trim($out[$n]) . "\t" . $line[11];
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents('out.tab', $out);
```

**Usage:**

- Position yourself in the `ballgown` directory
- Save the file with a name, let's say `script.php`
- Run the script with `php script.php`
- You'll find the output in the `out.tab` file

**Note:**

Let me know if you need further explanations regarding how to install and use PHP, what the script does and how to tweak it for a particular need.

---

Here's the same solution in **Python**, since the language was mentioned in the comments. This is the first time I write any Python, so please come forward with suggestions for improvements.

```
import os, glob
out = []
for k, filename in enumerate(glob.glob('*/t_data.ctab')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        file = f.readlines()
        for n, line in enumerate(file):
            line = line.split("\t")
            if n == 0:
                line[11] = os.path.dirname(filename) + "\n"
            if k == 0:
                out.append(line[5] + "\t" + line[11])
            else:
                out[n] = out[n].strip() + "\t" + line[11]
outfile = open('out.tab', 'w')
outfile.write("".join(out))
```

---

Same approach, written as a **Perl** one-liner:

```
perl -lane '$a[$n].=($a[$n]?"":$F[5])."\t".($n<1?$ARGV=~s#([-\w]+)\/.*$#$1#r:$F[11]); $n=eof?0:$n+1}{print "$_" for @a' */t_data.ctab
```

Comment: If i were to use scripting language, I would go with python.

Comment: @zee That's a good idea, please provide a Python solution.